# How to avoid the error Expected 1 argument but got 0 on Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my **JavaScript** function

```
function movements(remove) {
    var op = remove ? 'remove' : 'add';
    crossvent[op](documentElement, 'selectstart', preventGrabbed); // IE8
    crossvent[op](documentElement, 'click', preventGrabbed);
}     function move(value) {
```

And this is how it's called

```
movements();
```

You can find reference for in [jkanban.js](https://github.com/riktar/jkanban/blob/master/dist/jkanban.js) file.

Now I have to change it to Typescript and I got this error on function calling,

```
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0
```

How can I resolve this problem in typescript ?

Comment: It says movements can not be called without remove you need to pass parameter.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply add the question mark to the argument that requires your function, example:

```
function movements(remove?) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I get `TS1015: Parameter cannot have question mark and initializer.` when trying this

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the input for calling `movements()`.

You can set default to the variable using this:

```
function movements(remove = null) {
```

so that the function won't break even if you don't give it the input.

You can default it to anything you like though.

Comment: what is the difference between using `remove?` and `remove = null` ?

Comment: `remove?` makes the parameter optional; so you don't have to give it to the function when you call it. `remove = null` makes the parameter optional and also set default value to it, which in this case is `null`.

Comment: You can play around with this http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ to see how TypeScript compiled to JavaScript. Please try both options yourself to see what is happening. So you understand better.

Comment: `remove?` is in most cases (except for having several such arguments) identical to `remove = undefined`.